# copy specific data in one s3 bucket to another bucket using data pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

I have uploaded a JSON file in aws s3 bucket, as JSON file is in form of key and value, i want to copy only specific keys data into other s3 bucket using aws data pipeline. To do this operation what should i add in pipeline definition. Anyone with some clue would be really appreciable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Data Pipeline can run any kind of shell script through their ShellCommandActivity: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-shellcommandactivity.html

So you can setup a shell activity that will pull data from s3 (by using the "stage" capability), run some custom script, and push the data back to s3.